# host.json not respected by Visual Studio or web job

Tags: azure-webjobs, azure-queues

I have a queue processing application which is workign fine.  I am now trying to persuade the queue trigger to only process one item at a time.  My host.json is set up correctly, I think:

[image]

But when I run the app (either in Azure as a web job, or locally in Visual Studio), I see this:

[image]

I suspect that I am missing something really obvious, so wondering whether anyone has come across this before.  I have found a few articles, but nothing that gives me any insight into what I am doing wrong.

Adding the contents of program.cs.  I have tried adding "host.json" after the AddAzureAppConfiguration entry, but that makes no difference.

```
    class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        //var builder = new HostBuilder();
        var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();

        builder.ConfigureLogging((context, a) =>
        {
            a.AddConsole();
        });

        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
        {
            config.AddUserSecrets(
                "5aa19112-5ff7-467b-b062-f37c3654872d"); // This is automatic for a web app, but not for a console app
            var settings = config.Build();
            var connectionString = settings.GetConnectionString("AzureAppConfiguration");
            config.AddAzureAppConfiguration(connectionString);
        });

        builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
        {
            b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
            b.AddAzureStorage();
        });

        builder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddMemoryCache();
        });

        var host = builder.Build();

        using (host)
        {
            await host.RunAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could my answer solve your problem? If not, please give me more information about the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are using the Azure WebJobs SDK v3.x. **In v3.x, hosts.json does not work for WebJob**.

Instead, version 3.x uses the standard ASP.NET Core APIs, so you need to configure it using the ConfigureWebJobs method:

```
static async Task Main()
{
    var builder = new HostBuilder();
    builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
    {
        b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
        b.AddAzureStorage(a => {
            a.BatchSize = 8;
            a.NewBatchThreshold = 4;
            a.MaxDequeueCount = 4;
            a.MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
        });
    });
    var host = builder.Build();
    using (host)
    {
        await host.RunAsync();
    }
}
```

Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-pt/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#queue-storage-trigger-configuration

Comment: Thanks!  I eventually gave up and managed the queue manually, but this is good to know thank you.